# How to setup multiple websites, stores and store views in magneto 2?

Tags: magento2, php, multistore, ubuntu

1. Create a root category - **Catalog-> Categories-> Add Root Category**
2. Create a website, store and store view - **Stores-> All Stores**

   ```
       2.1 Create Website -> Create Website (Ex- Berlin Website)

       2.2 Create Store -> Select the website for which you want to create store and select root category which you created in step-1

       2.3 Create Store View -> Select the store which you created in step-2.2 and must set the status as enabled
   ```
3. Set the Base Url and Secure Base Url link - **Stores-> Settings-> Configuration-> General-> Web**

   ```
      (Ex- Your base url http://127.0.0.1/magento2.4.1/)

      3.1 Change scope(left top corner dropdown) to the website you created in step-2.1 (only select the website not store view i.e. Berlin Website)

      3.2 Change links both in Base Url, Base Link Url and Secure Base Url, Secure Base Link Url (http://127.0.0.1/magento2.4.1/berlin/)

      3.3 Save config
   ```
4. Open magento root directory - (Ex- magento2.4.1)

   ```
     4.1 Create a folder with the same name in link (here berlin)

     4.2 Copy index.php and .htaccess from magento root folder and paste it in berlin

     4.3 Open index.php and
   ```

   replace :-

   ```
       $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
       /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
       $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
       $bootstrap->run($app);
   ```

   with :-

   ```
      $params = $_SERVER;
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'berlin'; (Put here the webiste code which you given in step-2.1)
      $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
      $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

      /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
      $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
      $bootstrap->run($app);
   ```
5. Now run the below commands in berlin folder (replace the path below with the full path to the root of your Magento)-

   ```
      ln -s /var/www/html/magento2.4.1/app/ app

      ln -s /var/www/html/magento2.4.1/lib/ lib 

      ln -s /var/www/html/magento2.4.1/pub/ pub 

      ln -s /var/www/html/magento2.4.1/var/ var
   ```
6. Run the below commands in magento root folder

   ```
     sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

     sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

     sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

     sudo php bin/magento indexer:reset

     sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

     sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

     sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
   ```
7. Check the new Url (http://127.0.0.1/magento2.4.1/berlin/)

Comment: which error you are facing here? describe error.

Comment: Above is the solution of the question